# Running pdftotext x.pdf y.txt programatically in linux?

Tags: c, fork, pdftotext

```
char *readFile(char *path, char *buffer) {

    if(strcmp(getExtenstion(path), "pdf") == 0){
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) {
            execlp("pdftotext", path, "henok.txt");
        }

        wait(NULL);
        readTextFile("henok.txt", buffer);
    }

    else {
        readTextFile(path, buffer);
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

I want to read pdf file in c, but after scouring the web i know that it is too hard to read pdf file directly so that i use pdftotext command line tool in linux to convert the pdf to txt file. After converting the pdf i can then read the txt file.

```
-> pdftotext shell.pdf henok.txt
```

works fine in the shell but i want to run this command programmatically.

The above command shows an error, I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'henok.txt': No such file or directory.

Comment: the function: `fork()` has three kinds of returned values: 1) <0 indicates and error occurred  2) =0 indicates in the child process 3) >0 means in the parent process.  All three conditions need to be checked and properly handled

Comment: regarding: `if(pid == 0) {
            execlp("pdftotext", path, "henok.txt");
        }`  1) the parameter list needs to be terminated via a NULL  2) if the call to `execlp()` fails, the code will return.  So the next lines after the call should be: `perror( "execlp failed" );` and `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child process ends after starting the 'pdf2text' and not when pdf2text has finished converting. When the parent process detects the end of the child process, the text file is not created yet. For this to work, the child process should control the completion of the 'pdf2text' execution. To make it simpler, you do not need to fork, just use the 'system' command. For example,

```
// 20 is length of "pdf2text" + length of "henok.txt" + 2 spaces + NULL character
char * cmd = malloc (20 + strlen (path)); 
sprintf(cmd, "pdf2text %s henok.txt", path);
system(cmd);
free(cmd);
```